# Eclipse failing to open

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse IDE keeps failing to open. I've updated my java to the latest version, I've got the newest Eclipse Version. I'm running x64 Windows, it seems like the Error log is trying to use x32, but I've installed a x64 version of Eclipse. I tried re-installing the x64 version and it still didn't work.

In the Pastebin I've linked is the contents of the Log.

http://pastebin.com/An5CRq3e

EDIT: I'm using x64-bit version of Java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for copying/pasting the log - definitely helpful!

This line looks significant:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible
```

SUGGESTIONS:

1. From a command prompt:

   - cd into your Eclipse directory
   - type `eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState`
2. Rename (or delete) any old workspaces to force Eclipse to create a new workspace

Comment: Done that as you suggested, I'm getting a new error message.

This is the new error message: http://pastebin.com/0hA9EdZ1

Comment: Renaming my old Workspace fixed the issue! Thanks for the help.

Comment: My pleasure.  And thank you again for posting the error log - good work!

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, please check too next solution below, about org.eclipse.core.resources . This works for me !

Comment: You're a real lifesaver!

Answer (score 25):

The same happened to me: without renaming my workspace I just deleted the corrupted **`org.eclipse.core.resources`** folder in the workspace (`$ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/`) and then Eclipse started successfully again.

Yes, I had to re-import all my projects (as *Existing Projects*) into the workspace.

---

Refs: [Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/209016/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have also removed **org.eclipse.core.resources** folder from my Eclipse workspace :

```
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
```

And also run the command in command prompt:

```
>eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState
```

After doing this Eclipse should work without any problem.

OR

Open a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me :

1. **Rename** your workspace
2. **Open** eclipse / talend or any software based on eclipse that give you the error
   -- it will **recreate a new workspace** automacilly
3. **Copy** your projects' folders from your **old workspace** to **new workspace**
4. in eclipse(or your software based on eclipse) just **reimport** your projects from folder

done