# Error occurring when starting Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide

My computer was suddenly shut down due to a power failure shortly after I closed the IDE. Now, when I attempt to start the IDE, I am greeted with an error dialog which directs me to the log file.

The message I am given in the log file is as follows: "An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (88)"

Should the entire log file be needed, I have uploaded it [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_e3EmH2k7TPwQ4uMUlc7O_v0MsMZlrhp)

How may I remedy this error?

Comment: Does starting Eclipse with a fresh workspace work (on the command line: `eclipse -data my_new_workspace`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse failing to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214988/eclipse-failing-to-open)

Comment: @howlger yes, it did work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good. You might also try `eclipse -clean` to open the old workspace. If this does not work, you can try to switch from the new workspace to the old workspace copying all preferences (_File > Switch Workspace_). Otherwise, you have to import the projects from the old workspace (_File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace_).